# How to run the normal functionalities of buttons when using ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, fragment

Today was the first day I used **ViewPager** to swipe across screens in my activity. However, after adding the **ViewPager**, none of my buttons in any activities seem to work. I can only swipe between my activities. I don't understand as to why this happens so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is the PageAdapter class code:

PageAdapter.java

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new FragmentOne();
                break;
            case 1:
                return new FragmentTwo();
                break;
            case 2:
                return new FragmentThree();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Here is the Fragments code:

FragmentOne.java

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_log,container,false);
    }
}
```

FragmentTwo.java

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_remote_lock,container,false);
    }
}
```

FragmentThree.java

```
public class FragmentThree extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_my_keys,container,false);
    }
}
```

FragmentActivity.java

```
public class FragmentActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.damsara);
        PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

FragmentActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/damsara"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

The xml files i added to the fragment classes contain buttons with animations. however none of them work.

Comment: Can you please post your code..

Comment: Added it. Sorry, i wasnt sure if its even possible so i just wanted to know. but please do look into it and check if anything could be changed

Comment: You should write break at the end of each case of your switch statement.

Comment: Adding the break statement shows that the break statement is an unreachable statement